# How to set-up clang format to keep return type and protoype in the same line

Tags: c, format, clang-format

I am discovering clang-format. I set ColumnLimit to 120. Generaly speaking this works well, meaning set parameters of function on different lines.

```
void myLongFunctionNameMoreThan120Col(int foo,
                                      float barbar,
                                      float* aLongPointerName,
                                      float* anotherVeryLongPointerName);
```

But for long return type, the function name is on an other line than the return type:

```
LONGTYPE
myLongFunctionNameMoreThan120Col(int foo, float barbar, float* aLongPointerName, float* anotherVeryLongPointerName);
```

How to tell to clang-format to always behave as in the first case?

I tried longer variable names to force the format. The solution is not satisfying, I shouldn't have to modify my variable name.

```
LONGTYPE myLongFunctionNameMoreThan120Col(int foo,
                                          float barbarTotoLong,
                                          float* aLongPointerName,
                                          float* anotherVeryLongPointerName);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) about styling options specifies everything you need to know about any particular option.

The option you are looking for is `AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None`. The meaning of value `None` is described as:

> Break after return type automatically. PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine is taken into account.

Therefore you can additionally control desired behavior with `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine`.

I assume that clang-format will try to format code such that the total penalty of formatted code is as small as possible. So you need to set `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine` to a high value relatively to other penalty option values.

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. I tried these parameters yet. But AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType doesnt do anything in this specific case and PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine blocks ColumnLimit effects.

Comment: clang-format has some edge cases where it might not always "see" a better way to format code. This is what seems it is happening from my tests of your example. It seems to be happy with both having return type on its own line and in same line as function name. Have you tried to manually format code the way you want it and then tried to use clang-format on that code? I know that won't automatically change the code to your desired format, but its the best i can think of to keep it in somewhat consistent state.

Comment: Also make sure to use latest version of clang-format as bugs might have been fixed. I used a manually built version from git to test your examples.